# ubuntu install openssl-1.0.1a failed

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

Firstly, I removed the newest version of openssl from my ubuntu16.04, and then I downloaded openssl-1.0.1a from the official website.

tar -zxvf openssl-1.0.1a.tar.gz
cd ./openssl-1.0.1a

./config

sudo make

sudo make install

then I got a new directory ssl: 
/usr/local/ssl/ls

bin certs include lib man misc openssl.cnf private

but when I tried to see the openssl version:
openssl version -a

it displayed this:
The program "openssl" is currently not installed.

I don't know why I didn't install openssl successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.
I should create a link for my openssl.
The commands are here:

ln -s /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl

ln -s /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl /usr/include/openssl